# String convertion to Datetime and zone hourly

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

my problem is with a parser site through html, I extract the time in the format string.
I need to convert the string to datetime and then convert to your time zone.

Thanks

```
hora = soup.select('span.match-time')[0].get_text().strip( ' - ' )
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(hora, '%H:%M')

print (dt_obj)
input_time = datetime.strptime(dt_obj, '%H:%M').time()
utc_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.utcnow(), input_time)
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Montevideo')
salida = str(utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz))
```

**ERROR**
/

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 /Users/fa/Desarrollo/football/parser.py
1900-01-01 19:30:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fa/Desarrollo/football/parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    input_time = datetime.strptime(dt_obj, '%H:%M').time()
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datetime.datetime.strptime takes in a a string from which you want to parse out time, takes in a format in which you specify how the time is written into the string, and then it parses the string to extract out a datetime object.

Read that one more time to make sure you really get it. The reason why it produces an error should be obvious now! You are passing an object to a function that requires two strings.

Once you've parsed it as an object, you can call methods on it, like bellow:

```
>>> dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime("12:00", "%H:%M")
>>> dt_obj
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 0)
>>> dt_obj.hour
12
>>> dt_obj.minute
0
>>> dt_obj.time()
datetime.time(12, 0)
>>> dt_obj.year
1900
```

### edit 1:

From what I see, you extract hours and minutes and then proceed to construct datetime object with today's date/month/year by UTC standards. I can't quite make out what you do with the timezones though, so I'll leave the last two lines to you.

```
>>> dt_obj = datetime.strptime("12:00", "%H:%M")
>>> input_time = dt_obj.time()
>>> utc_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.utcnow(), input_time)
```

Or if you need it shorter

```
>>> dt_obj = datetime.strptime("12:00", "%H:%M")
>>> utc_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.utcnow(), dt_obj.time())
```

This gets you from `12:00` to `datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 12, 0)`

Comment: am new to python, what would be how would the corrected code?

Comment: @Fabián: Depends on exactly what you want to do though, from what I've figured out from above you want do to something like I did in my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

If the input time string such as `19:30` refers to UTC time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Montevideo')
time_string = '19:30'
utc_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.utcnow(), 
                          datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M').time())
dt = utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
# -> 2015-02-11 17:30:00 UYST-0200
```

If the input time is time in Uruguay:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Montevideo')
time_string = '19:30'
naive_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.now(tz), 
                            datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M').time())
dt = tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
# -> 2015-02-11 19:30:00 UYST-0200
```

Note: the result is different.